# How access to persistentDataPath child folders on IOS (Unity Deployment)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I develop an app for iOS (Ipad precisely) and I need to save a config file on the Ipad to save user progression. The documentation of Unity says to use Application.persistentDataPath to make update on a config file on Ipad. So, I used this and it's works on Unity editor, but when I deploy the app on Xcode I get this error at the execution :

Cannot load file : "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/.../Documents/Config/config.ini"

I work on Windows, so my Application.persistentDataPath is : "C:\Users\stagiaire\AppData\LocalLow\CompName\ProjectName"

At root of this structure, I have "Config/config.ini", so I expected that this configuration would be the same on iOS.

But when I check if these folders and/or files exist with :

```
if (Directory.Exists(UnityEngine.Application.persistentDataPath + "/Config/config.ini"))
```

XCode says that this file doesn't exists, but when I make this test :

```
if (Directory.Exists(UnityEngine.Application.persistentDataPath + "/"))
```

XCode says that this folder exists ??????

So, I don't understand. Unity create the structure of persistentDataPath and don't create the folders and files contained on this structure. It seems weird so I ask the question because I have no more idea to solve this problem.

Sorry for my poor english and thanks for your time.

Comment: One path exists and the other does not. Why is this a problem? If `.../Config/config.ini` is a file you create, you're going to have to create it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unity does not create a directory structure but instead gives you access to the *Documents* folder from the app's sandbox. That means you have to create your directories and files once when they are accessed the very first time.

```
string dir = Application.persistentDataPath + "/Config";
if (!Directory.Exists (dir)) {
    Directory.CreateDirectory (dir);
}
string configFile = dir + "/config.ini";
if (!File.Exists (configFile)) {
    File.Create (qcarFile);
}
```

BTW: If you call *Directory.Exists ()* passing a file name it will return false as the file is not a directory.

Comment: I tried but it seems not to work -_-. I'll try later.

Comment: `Directory.CreateDirectory` does nothing if the folder already exists, so you don't need that first if.